# MySQL simple replication problem: 'show master status' produces 'Empty set'?

Tags: mysql, database, replication, master-slave

I've been setting up MySQL master replication (on Debian 6.0.1) following these instructions faithfully: http://www.neocodesoftware.com/replication/

I've got as far as:

```
mysql > show master status;
```

but this is unfortunately producing the following, rather than any useful output:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The error log at `/var/log/mysql.err` is just an empty file, so that's not giving me any clues.

Any ideas?

This is what I have put in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on one server (amended appropriately for the other server):

```
server-id = 1
replicate-same-server-id = 0
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1
master-host = 10.0.0.3
master-user = <myusername>
master-password = <mypass>
master-connect-retry = 60
replicate-do-db = fruit
log-bin = /var/log/mysql-replication.log
binlog-do-db = fruit
```

And I have set up users and can connect from MySQL on Server A to the database on Server B using the username/password/ipaddress above.

Comment: I've also tried following the simpler instructions at: http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication (on one server alone) and again, when I get to `show master status` I see `Empty set`. Baffled!

Comment: Restart the service & check. If any error logs generated after restart, paste that also.

Answer (score 8):

Interestingly, I have mysql running on my PC with binary logs not enabled. I did the following:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 19
Server version: 5.5.12 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show master status;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show binary logs;
ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging

mysql>
```

As shown, since MySQL shows "Empty Set" for SHOW MASTER STATUS; because binary logging was not enabled. That's obvious given the configuration I have.

First thing you should do is make sure the error log has a specific folder

```
[mysqld]
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql.err
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-replication.log
```

Then run the following:

```
service mysql stop
mkdir /var/log/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
service mysql start
```

Then in the mysql client run these SQL Commands

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

If you get the same output I had before, then MySQL cannot write binary logs to the designated folder. Your dilemma becomes why MySQL cannot write to /var/log.

This is not a full answer but I hope this helps.

Comment: Setting /var/log to be recursively owned and with a group of mysql is going to break a linux system fairly badly. I strongly advise people not to do this. Instead, run that specifically on the log file which mysql is trying to write to, and if it's not there touch it first.

Comment: You know something, @JohnHunt ? You are right. I will change the folder.

Answer (score 1):

If thhe Mysql version is >5.0, your replication settings master-host, master-user, master-password and a few others in your my.cnf will be ignored. Use CHANGE MASTER TO for initial replication setup.

Compare http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto-slaveinit.html

Answer (score 0):

Your setting for `log-bin` is incorrect, so MySQL can't write binary logs. It isn't a filename, it is a partial filename *pattern,* to which MySQL will prepend a directory and append a sequence number and extension. The usual setting is something like

```
log-bin=log-bin
```

Check the manual.

Comment: `--log-bin=file_name` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin). What manual states that it isn't a filename?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amazon RDS or Aurora, remember to reboot the writer instance after applying `bin_log` in cluster parameter.

This needs to be done manually. Rebooting writer instance will also cause read replicas to reboot.

Before rebooting you will get `Empty set`.